# Savepoint on Flink Job Finish

Tags: apache-flink

I have a usecase where I need to seed a Flink Application(both RocksDB state and Broadcast State) using Bounded S3 sources and then read other unbounded/bounded S3 sources after the seeding is complete.

I was trying to achieve this in 2 steps:

1. Seeding: Trigger a Flink job with only the seeding data bounded source and take a savepoint after the job finishes.
2. Regular Processing: Restore from seeded savepoint on a new Flink graph to process other unbounded/bounded S3 sources.

Questions:

1. For Step 1: Does Flink support taking savepoints automatically after Job Finishes in Streaming Mode.
2. If only manual savepoint trigger is supported, what can be used a done signal that all the seeding data is processed completely and all the task are finished processing?

Any other approaches to achieve the seeding usecase is appreciated as well.
Note: Approaches where we buffer the regular data until seeding data is processed is not feasible for my usecase

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Using unbounded sources you can make use of [externalized checkpoint](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/checkpointing/) and you will be able to start/resume jobs from the checkpoint. Enabling this feature it is necessary to have a process to clean the checkpoints when the job is cancelled otherwise the checkpoints won't be deleted by Flink.
2. You can use the new feature available in Flink 1.15 ([checkpoints with finished tasks](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/checkpointing/#checkpointing-with-parts-of-the-graph-finished)) to do that.